# Начало вываливаться приложение с ошибкой

Tags: android

Приложение работало. Потом изменил код и работать перестало `AppName has stopped`, вернул код в исходную позицию, но работать приложение не начало...

Проблему я вроде локализировал но не могу понять куда дальше двигаться. В моем случае ошибка происходит на стадии создания моего `ArrayAdapter`, только как вести диагностику дальше - ума не приложу. Вот код метода `onCreate` для фрагмента:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Begin","starting DeviceListFragment");
        deviceArrayList = DevicesBase.getDevicesBase(getActivity()).getDeviceArrayList();
        Log.d("Begin"," creating Adapter");
        LaboratoryDeviceAdapter adapter = new LaboratoryDeviceAdapter(deviceArrayList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("end", " DeviceListFragment");
    }
```

**Вот отрывок кода для Адаптера:**

```
    private class LaboratoryDeviceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LaboratoryDevice> {          

        public LaboratoryDeviceAdapter(@NonNull List<LaboratoryDevice> objects) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, objects);
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
07-06 10:09:55.671 2364-2364/com.example.user.labtmp D/Begin: starting DeviceListActivity    
07-06 10:09:55.673 2364-2364/com.example.user.labtmp D/Begin: starting DeviceListFragment
07-06 10:09:55.679 2364-2364/com.example.user.labtmp D/Begin: com.example.user.labtmp.DeviceListActivity@788ced3 creating Adapter    
07-06 10:10:02.276 2220-2425/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/Tee: Incorrect start position: startPosition: 2146203647, mBufferBegin: 320000, mBufferEnd: 892160
```

Информации по данной ошибке не нашел в инете.

**UPD**. Я попробовал откатить изменения средствами Android studio на то время, когда приложение точно работало. И оно выдает тот же результат. Видимо проблема не в коде, а в Эмуляторе/IDE/SDK или еще в каком либо программном элементе. видимо, где-то что то умерло. Что делать то?

Comment: Сделайте wipe эмулятора... или создайте другой эмулятор

Comment: Приложенная ошибка на относится к вашему приложению. Снимайте стек-трейс сразу после краша приложения.

Comment: @eugeneek wipe эмулятора не помог. Помог совет со стек трейсом. Моя ошибка заключалась в том, что я не заметил включенного фильтра на logcat. Увидев полный стек трейс я понял, что ошибка кроется в результате моих манипуляций в CoordinatorLayout (неверное использование behavior и anchor). Оформите ваш коментарий в ответе в более развернутом виде - плюсану, если (или когда) позволит репутация)

Answer (score 1):

Если в твоем приложении есть google search box, то проверь его позицию

> startPosition: 2146203647, mBufferBegin: 320000, mBufferEnd: 892160
>   судя по ошибке - стартовая позиция этого бокса выходит за границы дозволенного.

Comment: да вот в том то и дело, что нет его.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с @eugeneek, что приложенные логи не имеют отношения к проблеме, как минимум на них не видно, чтобы в вашем приложении случалось что-то важное. Кстати, что именно перестало работать и как было раньше?

В любом случае, параметры конструктора Вашего адаптера выглядят крайне подозрительно. Во-первых, `ArrayAdapter` не имеет метода `getActivity()`, то есть Вы либо вызываете метод Вашего же адаптера `LaboratoryDeviceAdapter` и передаёте пустоту вместо контекста, либо `LaboratoryDeviceAdapter` объявлен как внутренний класс, чего делать явно не стоит во избежание утечек памяти. Во-вторых, надеюсь, что Вы переопределяете в адаптере метод `getView`, иначе у вас будет исключение, что ресурса с id 0 не существует (это второй параметр конструктора).

Обычно объявление адаптера выглядит примерно так:

```
public class LaboratoryDeviceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LaboratoryDevice> {

    public LaboratoryDeviceAdapter(Context context, List<LaboratoryDevice> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Настоятельно рекомендую узнать, что такое [View Holder](http://androiddocs.ru/pattern-viewholder-v-realizacii-spiska-listview/) и зачем он нужен, особенно, если у Вас сложный UI. Если там одно текстовое поле, то можно и так:

```
public class LaboratoryDeviceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LaboratoryDevice> {

    public LaboratoryDeviceAdapter(Context context, List<LaboratoryDevice> objects) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        view.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Но в простом случае удобнее не наследоваться от `ArrayAdapter`, использовать [SimpleAdapter](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/107-urok-48-ispolzuem-simpleadapter.html)

Comment: Кстати, что именно перестало работать и как было раньше? - Оно вообще перестало запускаться. Закрывается не отобразив фрагмент.
"либо LaboratoryDeviceAdapter объявлен как внутренний класс, чего делать явно не стоит во избежание утечек памяти." - это внутренний класс. Делал по примеру из книги Брайна Харди.
"надеюсь, что Вы переопределяете в адаптере метод getView" - так и есть

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на View Holder)